# How to build a push system in django?

Tags: django, websocket, push, message, orbited

I need to build a push system in django, basicly its function is to push messages from server to browser.

As nodejs cannot be used, i prefer websocket or orbited, but i've no idea how to implement any of these two in django. pls recommend a method for me, this will help me a lot, thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django isn't good at "pushing" things to the client. If django is your only option, the only way to mimic a push is via long-polling. But this is not efficient. Instead, websockets are hot. Tornado and twisted can help you here. There is also a more complete answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479741/django-push-http-response-to-users).

Comment: My whole site is based on django and Nginx, so I guess its not an efficient way to use Tornado or twisted right?

Comment: Why not efficient? Does it depend on your hardware? With little effort you can have a parallel tornado process that handles some websockets..

Comment: Sorry i am not quite familiar with tornado, do u mean a tornado server   parallel to django? My first thought was to do this inside django, cause there's django-websocket which is not too bad.

Comment: Yes, I mean a tornado server parallel to django. Django-websocket has some caveats, which are stated in its documentation. If you invest a little time, you'll have a simple tornado websocket server up and running. This is quite easy, see here to feel the simplicity :) http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2011/10/simple-websocket-push-server-using.html. Enjoy!!

Comment: This problem really bugs me for a long time, now i guess im close to the answer :) Thx

Comment: Long-polling is not inefficient (compared to polling). And Django can't do it (or websockets) directly.

Comment: As @potar pointed in another answer, [SwampDragon](http://swampdragon.net) is a good Django alternative using Redis.

Answer (score 14):

One option would be to use a WebSocket server running parallel to your Django server which has a REST/Push API, and then do pushes from Django by simply HTTP/POSTing to the WebSocket server, which in turn delivers the messages to all connected WebSocket clients.

That way, you don't need any structural/technical changes to your existing Django app, nevertheless have a scalable, modern WebSocket based push feature.

For a hosted service providing above, I'd have a look at http://pusher.com.

If you prefer running your own, I'd have a look at http://autobahn.ws, which is deployed as a ready-to-run virtual appliance (VMware, VirtualBox, Amazon EC2). You can find working examples of REST/API here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPushPython

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn Open-source, and work for Tavendo, which offers Autobahn.ws (the commercial offering based on Autobahn OSS).

Answer (score 9):

Another implementation of websockets in Django:
https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon

From docs: SwampDragon makes use of Djangos wonderful ORM, Tornados excellent websocket support (with fallback. Tested in IE7), and Redis blazing speed.

Answer (score 9):

As of 2016, there is [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable), which brings websockets to Django (1.8 and higher).

It is also [part of the official Django project](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2016/sep/09/channels-adopted-official-django-project/).

Comment: Found also a full tutorial for Django + Channels + React: https://codyparker.com/django-channels-with-react/

Answer (score 6):

There is a Django module, which supports websockets out of the box using Redis as message queue.
Have a look here: https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis

Disclaimer: I am the author of that library.

Comment: Can you recommend a minimal example?

Comment: @RubberDuck... Check the repository demo. It's pretty good. You can check your installation: http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#check-your-installation Here is the live demo:  http://websocket.aws.awesto.com/chat/

Answer (score 5):

As @hymloth suggests, a better way is to use tornado or node.js.

But, if you have to use Django, I've wrote an article about implementing WebSocket with it that you might find useful.

http://curella.org/blog/2012/jul/17/django-push-using-server-sent-events-and-websocket/

Answer (score 1):

[Django omnibus](https://github.com/moccu/django-omnibus)

Uses tornado internally and has python 3 support.