# Realtime web programming: how does it work?

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, websocket, push-notification

As a web developer, I have developed a chat service and some other real-time collaborative services with the help of third-party services like Redis or Pusher. They provide simple API's that I can use publish/subscribe model to achieve bidirectional communication over the webserver. I want to now implement a simple push notification without the use of any third-party services, but I am not quite sure how to achieve this. The situation is as below:

1. Backend is in Python (Django)
2. A user receives a private message from another user.
3. The recipient should be notified without having to refresh the web browser.

**My questions:**

1. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927505/how-to-build-a-push-system-in-django), Django seems a bad option to achieve such functionality while Node.js is a good one. Is it true? If it is, why is that?
2. Is it possible to open a websockets from client to the server, to listen to certain changes to a specific model? (ex. when there's a new message in Message model, update the DOM)

I appreciate any help a lot!

Comment: Basically you will need to set a javascript interval, and call an ajax function every n seconds to check for an update (new messages), that should be the overall behavior on a php/python implementation, in node you don't need to set a timeout, since the client js will ask the node server if there is a new message, and only when there is an update the server will send you that update, this is just to give you a heads up while somebody gives you a better answer. If it were me i'll use node.js, is exactly for this kind of applications that it was created.

Comment: Hi Zarich, thanks for your comment. But isn't that polling? I'd like to implement an actual "realtime" feature.

Comment: Yes, thats why node.js is better in this kind of things, but wait for a real answer =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSockets are exactly what you want here. They are however, a (comparatively) recent addition to browsers and as a result, support is not ubiquitous. [WebSocket Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets)

The websocket model allows you to connect a socket from a server to a client with a web browser, then send messages from the server and receive them asynchronously at the client and vice versa.

Because Node.js is Javascript and the chances are you will be writing your client in Javascript, it lends itself as a sensible choice for writing coupled components, such as in this scenario.

The most popular WebSocket library is [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) which was built for use with Node.js. With Socket.io, your notification model would look something like this:

**Server**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('notification', { name: 'Notification', message: 'It\'s here');
});
```

**Client**

```
var notifications = document.getElementById('nlist');
socket.on('notification', function(notification) {
   var div;
   // make some DOM changes
   document.title = notification.name;
   div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = notification.message;
   notifications.appendChild(div);
   socket.emit('received-notification');
});
```

Socket.io allows you to use custom event names, as shown here, which makes designing communication APIs that little bit easier. It also has fallbacks for XHR Long Polling and Flash sockets, in the circumstance that the user does not have Web Sockets.

Node will be faster than Django in this circumstance, but you may find that your codebase is more manageable in Django if this is your first venture into Node. It can be kinda difficult to design an application with a series of callbacks like this. I haven't ever used WebSockets with Django, but my experience with Tornado and WebSockets has been poor.

Comment: Thank you Dan! So in this case, am I using Node.js with Django, replacing Django's default webserver WSGI?

Comment: If you're going to use Node alongside Django, I'd take the time to get familiar with nginx, so that you can reverse proxy to either Node or Django, depending on the route you are handling. This is especially important if you are looking to scale to 100k concurrent connections as neither Node nor Django's inbuilt HTTP servers are as fast as Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need unidirectional communication as pushing notifications, you'll better have a look at [Server Side Events](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/sse-websockets-data-flow-http2/) instead of Websockets.

SSE is much easier to implement, it doesn't need any special protocol (just standard HTTP) and does automatic reconnection.
Creating private messages would be done using good old XMLHttpRequests and should be filtered on client-slide.

Node.js is pretty good for serving SSE: its event loop implementation only uses one thread to manage multiple persistent connections.

Have a look at [sse-pubsub](https://github.com/triblondon/node-sse-pubsub) which provides an easy way to send notifications.