# Developing a A web-based real time dashboard

Tags: mysql, ajax, python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, real-time-data

I want to consume kafka stream into mysql using Python; on top if which I want to build a realtime web based (web app) dashboard that will automatically be refreshed (ajax) on each data insert in the database.

After some searching, found a suggestion that ajax is not good for this purpose. 
**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056578/realtime-web-programming-how-does-it-work)** post said websockets are better than ajax in terms of Performance.

Because I am not sure on whats the best way to achieve this So your **expert** advice is needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to consume kafka stream into mysql using Python; on top if which I want to build a realtime web based (web app) dashboard that will automatically be refreshed (ajax) on each data insert in the database."*

... (wince!) ...

*Pretty-please* find someone among your peers who can save you from yourself.  (And is there any possible way that I can say this to you, such that you can "save face?"  I can't think of any.)  I'm not-at-all trying to have public fun at your expense. Please – "talk immediately to your manager.  (S)He, surely, can help you."

Comment: (slow claps) That wasn't  an impressive effort. BTW do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly not an expert in this field, however my company uses Elastic/Kibana to read in from Kafka topics and display the data on a dashboard. This is just one of many routes you can take, but it works very well for us. You can read a little more into it here:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part1