# Django + Sockets

Tags: python, django, sockets

Whats the best alternative to implement sockets with Django 1.5?

I'm willing to implement a chatroom and notification in my Django site.

I've already reviewed Socket.io and node.js but would like to know advantages/disadvantages of each.

Comment: Why exactly are you looking for an alternative? Have you tried anything and faced any issue? Does the alternative here mean that you can switch from Django to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at this post?

[Chatroom using Django, Redis, Node](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/)

After doing a lot of research and reading up on other push notifications based solutions for Django such as Django Web-Sockets and reading up on the limitations of Django when using web-sockets (see this: [Django Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479741/django-push-http-response-to-users)) I decided to go with the Redis/Node/Socket.io/Django stack.

Yes this means I am having to run a minimal Node Server but that mainly just acts as a router. I am currently successfully using this solution for a few hundred users.

Comment: I have currently managed to pull up a node.js server along with redis just like you suggeted. Thanks for the advice it seems like a whole new world to explore.

Comment: @GustavoReyes Glad this helped - yes it's quite exciting.

Comment: For anyone looking at this: the mentioned article is outdated and you'll need to make adjustments to make it work with Django 1.7+ and Socket.io 1.0+