# Python Django. How to update count in message and notification badges in real-time

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

i'm currently working on app where users can send messages to each other and also receive some notifications from server. I'm using bootstrap's glyphicons and badges for indication that user have unread messages. Here is screenshot:
[image]

Problem is, i can update it only when user himself reload or load a new page.
What i want is to send real-time notification about new message or notification. So user don't have to reload page for getting notification about new message.

How can i achieve this? For development i'm using Django framework. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481930/2011147)

Comment: here is nice thing for real time notifications http://swampdragon.net/documentation/

Comment: Baterson, thanks, i will look at this!